# JButton with actionlistener does not execute its code

Tags: java, jframe, jpanel, jbutton, actionlistener

I'm developing a litte game in my freetime, but i encountered a problem which i don't really understand why its happening.

```
public class PauseMenu extends JFrame {
       ...
/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public PauseMenu() {
           ...
    JButton btnContinue = new JButton("Continue");

    btnContinue.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            GamePanel.var.setPause(false);
            dispose();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnContinue);

    ...
}
```

This is the code which doesn't really work. It is a JFrame with three buttons(i cut out the other two). It is supposed to be a Pause menu, a "popup" when the key 'p' is pressed.
It works quite good, the problem is

> GamePanel.var.setPause(false);

This line should set a boolean on false, which then continues my game loop. But for some reasons it never executes, the boolean stays on true.
This Problem only occurred after i changed the main game window from JPanel to JFrame, so i could show other jframes. I link them both because they are quite long:

This is the old code with JPanel. The button worked with this code.

> https://github.com/westerwave/dogfight_remake/blob/master/main/Dogfight.java

Here is the current code (JPanel)

> https://github.com/westerwave/dogfight_remake/blob/master/main/GamePanel.java

(JFrame)

```
    public static GameFrame frame;
    public GamePanel game;

    public GameFrame() {
       setUndecorated(true);
       setResizable(false);
       setTitle("Dogfight-Frame");
       setSize(dim);
       setVisible(true);
       game = new GamePanel();
       getContentPane().add(game);
       frame = this;
    }
```

I hope i made myself clear on the question and that you can help me.

EDIT:
I made a mistake and relied on my paintComponent method to give me the information about the boolean. I now found out that the boolean is changed, so everything working as intended. But somehow does my gameloop not resume after i click that button

Comment: Why not use a [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)?

Comment: Can't you create a simpler example that reproduces just the part of your code that works and the code that does not work? Reading and understanding all your code is difficult.

Comment: The problem is only with the jbutton and the change of the boolean, i added the rest for context.

Comment: I discovered the solution to my problem, I only had to change my input from InputMap and ActionMap to a KeyListener and that solved it (somehow). Thank you for your answers, they helped me in finding the real problem!

Comment: Make sure you've declared the *pause* variable in Vars as *volitile*. I'd also place some output right before the condition in the main game loop to dump the alue of Vars.getPause() just as a check

Comment: maybe the var is changing its value many times on others routines called.. i could debug the setPause(boolean) method and verify whether the program flow is binding there..

Answer (score 0):

That should work properly, I suspect some confusion here.

What if you put a breakpoint into the `actionPerformed()` method (or simply put a `System.out.println()` statement there)? Is it reached/executed?

Good luck with the project, seems fun!

Comment: This is the problem. As i wrote, dispose gets called and the frame vanishes but the pause boolean does not change